# JTree as JComboBox Element won't show JTree

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox, jtree

Im trying to put a number of JTrees into a JCombobox, the following didn't work:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode;

public class TestDialog extends JDialog {
public TestDialog(){
    super();
    JComboBox<JTree> cb = new JComboBox<>();

    DefaultMutableTreeNode firstRoot = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("First Root Node");
    DefaultMutableTreeNode firstChild = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("First Child Node");
    DefaultMutableTreeNode secondChild = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Second Child Node");
    firstRoot.add(firstChild);
    firstRoot.add(secondChild);

    JTree firstTree = new JTree(firstRoot);
    cb.addItem(firstTree);

    DefaultMutableTreeNode secondRoot = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Second Root Node");
    DefaultMutableTreeNode childOfSecondNode = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Child of Second Node");
    secondRoot.add(childOfSecondNode);

    JTree secondTree = new JTree(secondRoot);
    cb.addItem(secondTree);

    add(cb);

    pack();
    setVisible(true);
}
}
```

The Dialog doesn't show the actual JTree as selectable elements of the JCombobox but two long strings like `javax.swing.JTree[,0,0,0x0,invalid,...]`.
My question is, how do I fix this?

Comment: *"..trying to put a number of JTrees into a JCombobox"* ... ***Why?***

Comment: I'd like to have the elements grouped. An example would be a combobox to select different cars, the root node of the JTrees would be the car manufacturer and the child nodes the different car types. This way the cars would be "sorted" by car manufacturer for better accessibility.

Comment: Use multiple combo boxes. When a user chooses a manufacturer in the first, populate the 2nd with the models of car they make. Either that, or just use a standard `JTree` sans combo boxes. I cannot see any benefit, and more than a few downsides, to trying to cram a tree into a combo box.

Comment: Is it possible to have nested `Comboboxes`, as the list of manufacturers would be pretty big, and the manufacturers shouldn't be the main part of the UI.

Comment: *"the list of manufacturers would be pretty big"* No problem. The user can type the first letters and the combo will jump to the relevant entry. But I fail to see how 'nesting' them would improve things. It sounds like so much poorly thought out gibberish.

Comment: I reread your previous comment and now understand what you meant, thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding a `JTree` to a `JComboBox`, you could add a `DefaultMutableTreeNode` and use the `TreeCellRenderer` to draw the cells of the `JComboBox`.

[image]

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultTreeModel;
import javax.swing.tree.TreeCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.tree.TreeModel;

public final class MainPanel {
  private Component makeUI() {
    DefaultMutableTreeNode firstRoot = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("First Root Node");
    DefaultMutableTreeNode firstChild = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("First Child Node");
    DefaultMutableTreeNode secondChild = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Second Child Node");
    firstRoot.add(firstChild);
    firstRoot.add(secondChild);

    DefaultMutableTreeNode secondRoot = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Second Root Node");
    DefaultMutableTreeNode childOfSecondNode = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Child of Second Node");
    secondRoot.add(childOfSecondNode);

    DefaultMutableTreeNode hiddenRoot = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Root");
    hiddenRoot.add(firstRoot);
    hiddenRoot.add(secondRoot);

    JPanel p = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    p.add(new TreeComboBox(new DefaultTreeModel(hiddenRoot)), BorderLayout.NORTH);
    p.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    return p;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
      JFrame f = new JFrame();
      f.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      f.getContentPane().add(new MainPanel().makeUI());
      f.setSize(320, 240);
      f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      f.setVisible(true);
    });
  }
}

class TreeComboBox extends JComboBox<DefaultMutableTreeNode> {
  public TreeComboBox(TreeModel model) {
    super();
    DefaultMutableTreeNode root = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) model.getRoot();
    DefaultComboBoxModel<DefaultMutableTreeNode> m = new DefaultComboBoxModel<>();
    Collections.list((Enumeration<?>) root.preorderEnumeration()).stream()
        .filter(DefaultMutableTreeNode.class::isInstance)
        .map(DefaultMutableTreeNode.class::cast)
        .filter(n -> !n.isRoot())
        .forEach(m::addElement);
    setModel(m);
  }

  @Override
  public void updateUI() {
    super.updateUI();
    JTree dummyTree = new JTree();
    TreeCellRenderer renderer = dummyTree.getCellRenderer();
    ListCellRenderer<? super DefaultMutableTreeNode> r = getRenderer();
    setRenderer((list, value, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus) -> {
      Component c = r.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);
      if (value == null) {
        return c;
      }
      if (index < 0) {
        String txt = Arrays.stream(value.getPath())
            .filter(DefaultMutableTreeNode.class::isInstance)
            .map(DefaultMutableTreeNode.class::cast)
            .filter(n -> !n.isRoot())
            .map(Objects::toString)
            .collect(Collectors.joining(" / "));
        ((JLabel) c).setText(txt);
        return c;
      } else {
        boolean leaf = value.isLeaf();
        JLabel l = (JLabel) renderer.getTreeCellRendererComponent(
            dummyTree, value, isSelected, true, leaf, index, false);
        int indent = Math.max(0, value.getLevel() - 1) * 16;
        l.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(1, indent + 1, 1, 1));
        return l;
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

`JCombobox` can only represent `Strings`. `Objects` cannot be represented.

Comment: *"`Objects` cannot be represented."* a) A `String` **is an** `Object`. b) Of course they can. With an appropriate [renderer](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JComboBox.html#setRenderer(javax.swing.ListCellRenderer)), we could put a `File`, a `Font`, a `BufferedImage` or a POJO into a combo box.